# Noindex Nofollow de sites iguais

Tags: google, seo, robots.txt

Tenho dois sites iguais, mesmos conteúdos, design, tudo (Um é de homologação o outro de produção). Estão em domínios diferentes, única coisa que mudo, é no Robots que um está indexado `index follow`, e o outro está `noindex nofollow`, gostaria de saber se vou ter problema de conteúdo duplicado com esses sites?

Answer (score 0):

Fazendo uma atualização da resposta.

Exite mais uma forma de fazer o bloqueio que seria direto pelo *Cabeçalho de resposta HTTP* usando a **X-Robots-Tag**

Em vez de uma metatag ou `robots.txt`, você também pode retornar um cabeçalho `X-Robots-Tag:noindex` na resposta a uma solicitação de página. Aqui está um exemplo de uma resposta HTTP com um **`X-Robots-Tag`** que instrui os rastreadores a não indexar uma página:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Date: Tue, 25 May 2010 21:42:43 GMT
(…)
X-Robots-Tag: googlebot: nofollow
X-Robots-Tag: otherbot: noindex, nofollow
(…)
```

Aqui tem mais informações sobre **X-Robots-Tag**: https://developers.google.com/search/reference/robots_meta_tag

Outra dica sobre as Tag `<meta>` é que vc pode bloquear por elas Bots específicos como por exemplo:

```
<meta name="googlebot" content="NOINDEX, NOFOLLOW">
<meta name="MSNBot" content="NOINDEX, NOFOLLOW">
```

Bloqueio pelo `robots.txt` do site que vc não quer que seja indexado:

```
User-agent: *
Disallow: /
```

No `User-agent: *` o `*` significa que esta seção se aplica a todos os robôs.

E o `Disallow: /` diz ao robô que não deve visitar nenhuma página no site.

Outra coisa, o `Noindex Nofollow` deve ser inserido em uma meta tag `<meta>` não dentro do `robots.txt`! O correto deveria ser:

```
<html>
<head>
<title>...</title>
<META NAME="ROBOTS" CONTENT="NOINDEX, NOFOLLOW">
</head>
```

De qualquer forma a tag `<meta>` pode ser ignorada por alguns motores de busca, assim como o `robots.txt` principalmente os malware-robots. E o `nofollow` só bloquei os links da página em que está, se existir algum link para o seu site em alguma outra página que não tenha também o `nofollow` o *bot* pode achar seu site por esse link, tendo o robots ou não.

- Fonte: https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/93710?visit_id=1-636494476680720629-897891553&rd=1
- Fonte: http://www.robotstxt.org/meta.html